# .Net Image Resizer in Orchard

Tags: c#, .net, orchardcms, image-resizing, imageresizer

Currently having issues with .net imageresizer v 3.4.3.130. I have implemented it as so with the ability to pass in different sets of instructions for resizing:

```
public bool Upload(string fileName, string contentType, byte[] fileData)
{
    var extension = string.Empty;
    if (contentType == "image/jpeg")
        extension = "jpg";

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        //large
        string filePath = String.Format("ftp://{0}/{1}-large.{2}", _ftpHost, fileName, extension);

        ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(fileData, ms, _largeInstructions));

        _ftpClient.Upload(filePath, _ftpUsername, _ftpPassword, ms.ToArray());

    } //Repeated for different image sizes & appropriate instructions.



    return true;
}
```

However, when I call the function and pass in the raw image data I get the following exception.

{"Method not found: 'Void ImageResizer.ImageJob..ctor(System.Object, System.Object, ImageResizer.Instructions)'."}

This code part of a MVC.Net application that we are wrapping up in the Orchard CMS.

Could this be due to a conflicting assembly or something else entirely?

Comment: .net imageresizer v 3.4.3.103 not .130

Comment: So you're getting a Method Not Found at runtime, but not at compile-time? That = means you're compiling against a different DLL than you're running against.

Comment: How can I accurately determine where the one I am compiling against is coming from?

Comment: The version that comes with Orchard 1.9 is that exact same version. You can find it under `lib\imageresizer`.

Comment: +user3060716 You can determine where the lib is coming from by selecting the reference in the `References` node of your project and hitting `F4`, the upcoming dialog will display a property named `Path`, that is the location of the lib.